# Running twistd with Pypy

Tags: twisted, pypy, twistd

I'm trying Pypy because it shows [impressive benchmarks](http://speed.pypy.org) over CPython. Also, I'm mostly using the Twisted library in my code. I can now run a benchmark script which uses the Twisted reactor so I guess my setup is good. However, I do not know how to run the Twisted daemonizer (twistd) using Pypy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do it explicitly at run-time:

```
~$ /usr/bin/pypy /usr/bin/twistd ...
```

This works because it specifically starts PyPy and tells it to start interpreting the twistd script.

Or you can do it persistently at install-time:

```
~/Twisted-11.0.0$ /usr/bin/pypy setup.py install
```

This works because distutils (what setup.py uses) rewrites the **#!** line of each script it installs to point to the interpreter used to do the installation.  So **#!/usr/bin/env python** in the installation source becomes **#!/usr/bin/pypy** in the installed copy.

Comment: `~$ /usr/bin/pypy /usr/bin/twistd ...`  This only worked when I installed setuptools using pypy. If not, the pkg_resources module in twistd can not be found.

Comment: `~/Twisted-11.0.0$ /usr/bin/pypy setup.py install`  On Debian testing, this ended with a "Too many open files" error when the .egg was being extracted/installed. I had to use a higher open files limit using ulimit.

Comment: The "Too many open files" issue is documented here https://bugs.pypy.org/issue878 and is due to the way setuptools deals with files. Because pypy does not do reference counting GC, it might not GC/close files until much later. This is pretty bad, as it might happen when installing twisted alone, or as a dependency in pip - especially when it's a dependency of something else, it breaks everything.